# Making a change on a copy of a redux state also updates the actual state on redux store

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, state

I am seeing this behaviour where if i copy a redux state to a local variable and make a change to that variable it also updates my redux store without me using any kind of dispatching, here is my code:

```
// here is my action type inside my reducer 
case SET_USERS:
      return {
        ...state,
        users: action.payload,
      };

// and here i have a helper function to select a specific state and pass it to useSelector later on
export const getUsersSelector = (state: RootState) => {
  return state.app.users;
};
```

and i am accessing my state like this inside a custom hook `useUsers` i have

```
export const useUsers = () => {
   const users = useSelector(getUsersSelector);
   return {users}
}
```

and i am accessing my `users` value in another component using the `useUsers` hook:

```
const ListUsers = () => {
    const {users} = useUsers()
    //i make a copy of my users state
    const copyOfUsers = users
    
    //and update the copied variable
    copyOfUsers.push({name: 'John'})

    retunr (<View>{copyOfUsers.map((user)=><Text>{user.name}</Text>)}</View>)
}
```

the issue i am having is pushing a new item to my `copyOfUsers` variable also updates the `users` state inside the redux store, i dont know why this is happening and if its a normal behaviour, just wanted to know if this is a bug or intentional behaviour of redux? or how i can avoid it?

Comment: `const copyOfUsers = users` doesn't make a copy of the array, it just point a new variable to the same array. try with: `const copyOfUsers = users.slice()`

Comment: thanks for your comment but i want to understand why this is happening, ideally a state shouldn't be updated unless you dispatch an action to do so

Comment: but shouldn't states only be updated with a dispatch?

Comment: are you using react toolkit?

Comment: no i am not using redux toolkit

Comment: @Surafel Try `const copyOfUsers = [...users];` before mutating it.

Comment: The original comment explains why this is happening quite succinctly already I think. This is a JavaScript issue and not really specific to redux - `dispatch` is the correct way to update a redux store, yes, but there is nothing special about the objects in a redux store which means they wouldn't also be affected mutating their references directly as you have done in your example. The same goes for React state.

Comment: To sum it up, it's intentional behavior of mutable data structures in JS in general, and you can avoid it by making shallow a shallow copy of the array with `[...originalArray]` or `originalArray.slice()` (there might be more methods like this).

Comment: hm, interesting just found it weird that i never noticed this before, thanks for the explanations all.

Comment: if one of you can add your explanation as an answer i can accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually altering `shallow copy` of the `users` instance.

You should first create a `deep copy` of the `users` instance and then operate on the data.

The users is an `Array` so, you could have used `slice` to create a deep copy and then should have pushed the new object in the new copy of the users. That would have prevented the reflection of mutation in your redux copy.

Your code should look like:

```
 const {users} = useUsers()
 const copyOfUsers = users.slice() // this is actually created a deep copy of your array.

copyOfUsers.push({name: 'John'}) // changing the new memory data 
hence will not reflect in redux state.
```